# Function name not found due to reference error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting the following error in the console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jason is not defined
```

Here is my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function jason() {

    console.log("test");    
});   

var addEvent = function(object, type, callback) {
    if (object == null || typeof(object) == 'undefined') return;
    if (object.addEventListener) {
        object.addEventListener(type, callback, false);
    } 
};


addEvent(window, "resize", jason());
```

Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: how would I write this if I just want to call the function jason()?

Comment: Note that even if `jason` was accessible at this point, it would not be jason that you would pass as `callback`, but its return value (i.e `undefined`).

Comment: take the function body outside from the `ready()` & place it elsewhere. you can just call it by name inside the ready then. like `$(document).ready(jason());`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you put it inside `$(document).ready()` it is not available outside that function. Make it global and define it without `$(document).ready()`, but this will run even before  the page loads.

```js
function jason() {

    console.log("test");    
};   

var addEvent = function(object, type, callback) {
    if (object == null || typeof(object) == 'undefined') return;
    if (object.addEventListener) {
        object.addEventListener(type, callback, false);
    } 
};


addEvent(window, "resize", jason());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

In Javascript, there are many ways to define functions.  They generally fall into two categories though: function declarations and function expressions.

**Function declarations** look like this:

```
function jason() {
    console.log("test");    
}
```

A function declaration has global scope regardless of where it is in the code, and it can be called earlier in the program than where it is defined.  (*Edit: actually, if a function declaration is nested within another function, then it can only be called within that outer function*)

**Function expressions** look like this:

```
// Anonymous function expression set to a variable
let jason = function() {
    console.log("test");    
};

// Named function expression set to a variable
let jason = function freddy() {
    console.log("test");    
};
```

They are scoped just like any other variable.  They must be set before they can be called.

**In your case**, you created `jason()` as a function expression but didn't assign it to a variable.  You did name it `jason`, but that name only works inside of the function (like for recursion), not elsewhere.  If you were only going to use the `jason()` function as an argument to `$(document).ready()`, then defining as you did would be ok.  But since you seem to want to use `jason()` in more than one place, you either need to 1) change it a function declaration or 2) make it a function expression that is assigned to a variable prior to being passed to `$(document).ready()` and `addEvent()`.

By the way, when passing a function as an argument, you need to leave off the parentheses, like this:

```
$(document).ready(jason);
addEvent(window, "resize", jason);
```

If you do the following instead, it will execute `jason()` and pass the value it returns to each of those funtions.  In this case, that value would be `undefined`.

```
// Not what you want
$(document).ready(jason());
addEvent(window, "resize", jason());
```

Comment: Re "A function declaration has global scope regardless of where it is in the code" - nested functions are not made global. Good point that the callback to pass is `jsan` and not `jsan()`

Answer (score 1):

[Function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function) can be given a name, but as noted in the MDN link, the name is only available within the function's body.

Function declarations which cause a named function to be hoisted to the top of the function or script element in which they reside are also [function *statements*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function).

Naming and providing the code for `jsan` as an argument value for a call to `ready` prevents it being treated as a statement and creates a function expression.

Obviously if you want to call or reference the `jsan` function in multiple places it needs to be declared *in the scope of everywhere it's referenced* - which could require creating a global function or declaring it in a common outer function, depending on the structure of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Jason is wrongly define. Just check the below code, first you define a function and then call it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    addEvent(window, "resize", jason());

    console.log("test");    
});   

var addEvent = function(object, type, callback) {    
    if (object == null || typeof(object) == 'undefined') return;
    if (object.addEventListener) {
        object.addEventListener(type, callback, false);
    } 
};

   function jason(){
    console.log("call jason function");
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write your code just in document .ready function().

```js
  

$(document).ready(function(){
console.log("test");
})

var addEvent = function(object, type, callback) {
    if (object == null || typeof(object) == 'undefined') return;
    if (object.addEventListener) {
        object.addEventListener(type, callback, false);
    } 
};


addEvent(window, "resize");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```